# AWS MSK Storage: Is it possible to have different storage size brokers in AWS MSK cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

AWS MSK Storage:

1. Is it possible to have different storage size brokers in AWS MSK cluster?
2. How to scale down MSK broker storage size? please suggest me the best way to do it.
3. What are the risks if scale down the storage of broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers:

> Is it possible to have different storage size brokers in AWS MSK cluster?

Storage size (EBS volume size) is the same for each broker, it is not possible to have different volumes, and there are no workarounds for that

> How to scale down MSK broker storage size? please suggest me the best way to do it.

It's not possible currently to downsize the volume storage.

The workaround is to migrate to a new cluster with less storage provisioned and terminate the existing one.